Display prev / next posts links from the same category with thumbnails in Wordpress
I am no so good in PHP and I would like to ask someone for help:
I want when I am in single post, to show something like related posts to this that I am in. But arrows links with thumbs to next and previous posts from the same category the post is.
I use this code and it kinda works.
<div class="previous-post-link">
                <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<< Previous Post', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'listing_category'); ?>                    
            </div>

            <div class="next-post-link">
                <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post >>', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'listing_category'); ?> 
            </div> 
    

But I would like to show the posts thumbnails.
I want to get only Next/Prev posts from the same taxonomy category.
Later I will use CSS to have something like in the photo below:

thanks!

can you be more specific about how it would know which category is the category you want? Posts can have multiple categories, and if you're on an author/date archive the user might expect it to be the next post from that archive too. When you click on a post in a category archive/list the post doesn't know that context, it only knows what's currently in the URL

Hi, lets say posts are only in one category not two or more. And this option I need only in the single post not in authors archive. Something like related posts but Next and Previous from the same category the post you are in.

Are you using the Block Editor? The Query block might at least get you close.

No, i don't use it. Thanks.

So I asked ChatGPT and it comes with a working solution for me:
    <?php 
    $prev_post = get_previous_post(true, '', 'listing_category');
    if (!empty($prev_post)) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev_post->ID); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($prev_post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
            << <?php echo esc_html($prev_post->post_title); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="next-post-link">
    <?php 
    $next_post = get_next_post(true, '', 'listing_category');
    if (!empty($next_post)) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_post->ID); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <?php echo esc_html($next_post->post_title); ?> >>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

Explanation:
get_previous_post($in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $taxonomy): Retrieves the previous post object. The $in_same_term argument ensures that the post is from the same category or taxonomy term (listing_category in your case).
get_next_post($in_same_term, $excluded_terms, $taxonomy): Similarly, this retrieves the next post object.
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, $size): Fetches the post thumbnail for the specified post ID. The size 'thumbnail' is used, but you can change this to any other size, like 'medium' or 'large'.
get_permalink($post->ID): Gets the URL for the post.
Notes:
Ensure that your posts have featured images (thumbnails) set, as this code relies on them.
You can style the output as needed by adding custom CSS.
This code should give you the desired result, displaying the previous and next posts' titles along with their thumbnails, all within the same taxonomy category.
